# Creating Regex for url path

Tags: c#, regex

im very new to regex and have been trying to create an expression which creates validation for a path. Below are the rules I would like to include

- MUST begin and end with forward slash e.g /example/
- path name must be between 1-63 characters
- no upper case characters allowed
- no spaces
- can only contain the following symbols "-", ".", "_", "~"

This is what I currently have `^((?/)[a-z0-9]{1,63}/)$`

Can someone please tell me how to include the rules above?

Thankyou!

EDIT image showing error on regex101.com

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZIvc.png)

Comment: This does not look correct `(?/)` I think just `^/[a-z0-9._~-]{1,63}/$`

Comment: Or, if the slashes must count in the overall limit, `^(?=.{1,63}$)/[a-z0-9._~-]+/$`

Comment: Thankyou both for the prompt response! I have checked this on regex101.com and both expressions have an error on the slashes?

Comment: @Sock12 It depends on the language that you use/select. If you change the language to Python, or change the delimiter to something different than `/` when selecting pcre it works. See this demo https://regex101.com/r/L5sIeS/1 with a selected delimiter of a percentage sign, or just select C# as the language https://regex101.com/r/HZWoUm/1

Comment: In C# code where you define regexes with regular or verbatim string literals, you do not need to escape slashes as they are not special regex chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You can answer it if you want.

Comment: @Sock12 Which regex works best for you?

Comment: I have used the one that you suggested @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^/[a-z0-9._~-]{1,61}/$
```

Or, if you plan to add more specific parts to the pattern, a lookahead version will become handier:

```
^(?=.{1,63}$)/[a-z0-9._~-]+/$
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/yOBvNp/2) and [regex demo#2](https://regex101.com/r/yOBvNp/1). Note that in the C# code, where you define regexes with regular or verbatim string literals, you do not need to escape slashes as they are not special regex chars.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `(?=.{1,63}$)` - a positive lookahead that requires the string to contain one to 63 chars other than line break chars till the end of string
- `/` - a `/` char
- `[a-z0-9._~-]{1,61}` - one to 61  lowercase ASCII letters, digits, `.`, `_`, `~`, or `-` chars
- `[a-z0-9._~-]+` - one or more lowercase ASCII letters, digits, `.`, `_`, `~`, or `-` chars
- `/` - a `/` char
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score -1):

Try RegexPlus or dk.brics.automaton, as it allows &-operator so that you could write:

/(\w{1,63})&(http...)/